# Run Programs at a specific physical (bureau) location

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, automation, geolocation

I use my laptop at multiple different workplaces, through the use of docking stations.

One of these Workplaces (my home) has some specific hardware that requires specific software to run correctly, which can be quite resource intensive when idling.
At the moment I disable auto-run for this software and start it manually whenever I get home, which I sometimes forget, which causes all kinds of annoyances.

Since Windows can recognize different workplaces and correctly set up all monitors and desktops that workplace uses, I was wondering if it was possible to tell windows to open some specific programs when connected to a distinct workplace?

I would tolerate a single lightweight software that would always run in the background to make this happen.